# Rtsp h264 missing plugin

Tags: windows, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to receive a live H264 stream from a wireless camera using RTSP. The camera IP is 192.168.150.1 and it doesn't require authentication.

Since I'm developing under windows, I installed Gstreamer 1.0 - 1.8.3, a complete installation, with all the plugin and everything selected during the installation process.

When I try the pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.150.1" latency=100 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

I receive this output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.150.1
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: No supported stream was found. You might need to allow more transport protocols or may otherwise be missing the right GStreamer RTSP extension plugin.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(6421): gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I also tried the following command:

```
gst-play-1.0 rtsp://192.168.150.1
```

getting this output:

```
Interactive keyboard handling in terminal not available.
Now playing rtsp://192.168.150.1
Pipeline is live.
ERROR Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in. for rtsp://192.168.150.1
ERROR debug information: gsturidecodebin.c(1006): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
gstrtspsrc.c(6421): gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source
Reached end of play list.
```

When I try the same URL (rtsp://192.168.150.1) in VLC I can see the stream. So my guess is that I'm missing "the right GStreamer RTSP extension plugin"

The output of `inspect-1.0 | grep 264` is:

```
File STDIN:
x264:  x264enc: x264enc
videoparsersbad:  h264parse: H.264 parser
typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264
rtp:  rtph264depay: RTP H264 depayloader
rtp:  rtph264pay: RTP H264 payloader
openh264:  openh264dec: OpenH264 video decoder
openh264:  openh264enc: OpenH264 video encoder
libav:  avdec_h264: libav H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 decoder
libav:  avmux_ipod: libav iPod H.264 MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14) muxer
```

I also tried using FFmpeg and I can see the video, but I prefer using Gstreamer because I'm going to use the same configuration (camera, pipeline, gstreamer library...) on an Android device, and in my opinion Gstreamer seems to be the best choice.

From FFmpeg I got this info about the stream

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 640x352, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

Does anyone have some advices to sort this thing out?
Wich plugin am I missing? And how can I to add in my installation?

**Edit:**
The output of `gst-launch-1.0.exe -v playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.150.1`

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = rtsp://192.168.150.1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstRTSPSrc\)\ source"
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.150.1
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
gsturidecodebin.c(1006): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
gstrtspsrc.c(6421): gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: can you try gst-inspect-1.0 rtspsrc - what does that say?

Comment: @SamerTufail It prints the whole "documentation" for _rtspsrc_

Comment: that means you have the required rtspsrc plugin, can you try gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin2 uri=rtsp://192.168.150.1 - if this doesn't play what are the messages produced by the verbose

Comment: @SamerTufail Edited question (I think playbin**2** is in the 0.1 version of Gstreamer)

Comment: true, playbin should be fine. Can you try rooting out the missing plugin by breaking your pipline down doing gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.150.1" latency=100 ! fakesink  If this shows incoming packets on your console add more plugins b.w your rtspsrc and the fakesink like  - rtspsrc ! rtph264depay ! fakesink - do not forget the -v on gst-launch-1.0

Comment: @SamerTufail even with just a simple pipeline as the one you suggested (rtspsrc -> fakesink) I got almost the same output as my first pipeline in this post, wich contains the message: _No supported stream was found. You might need to allow more transport protocols or may otherwise be missing the right GStreamer RTSP extension plugin._

Comment: try with another rtsp source for e.g https://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html - try these sources first with vlc and then with gstreamer.

Comment: @SamerTufail It seems those links are not working anymore (even VLC can't play rtsp link. The other one is 404)

Comment: Try another source just google for them and try an alternate rtsp source

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem with GStreamer/1.8.3.

And the reason was that my camera did not provide the ["Control URL"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#appendix-C.1.1) attribute in it's session descriptions, while GStreamer is not smart enough to fall back to the base URL in this case (like other players do).

So, I ran the following command to get detailed logs from GStreamer:

```
gst-play-1.0 rtsp://camera_ip:port/ --gst-debug-level=9 --gst-debug-no-color &> GSTREAMER_LOGS.txt
```

In the logs I found this line:

```
DEBUG  rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:6109:gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams:<source> skipping stream 0x7f01b402c140, no setup
```

Then looking into the current [gstrtspsrc.c](https://github.com/Kurento/gst-plugins-good/blob/4560fcb5ce0235517a020a1ba68a269a1d84df21/gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.c) code from Kurento's gst-plugins-good bundle, I found that "skipping stream ..., no setup" error only happens when `stream->conninfo.location == NULL`. And that, as I said, happened because my camera didn't provide the "Control URL" attribute in SDP. Adding the following line to my camera SDP session descriptions solved the issue for me:

```
a=control:*
```

But, generally, this probably needs to be fixed in GStreamer code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a limitation of GStreamer that isn't shared by VLC and ffmpeg. I have a similar situation here, where I have three different RTSP cameras, two that work fine with GStreamer and one that doesn't. All three work fine with VLC and ffmpeg.

I used Wireshark to look at the raw RTSP protocol and found that the two cameras that work with GStreamer include an sprop-parameter-sets parameter field, while the one that doesn't work doesn't have this field.

The information encoded in sprop-parameter-sets (the SPS and PPS data) is usually present in the RTP stream that comes from the camera. Apparently VLC and ffmpeg are smart enough to pick this up, but GStreamer is not.

I tried to manually insert the sprop-parameter-sets data by using the caps command line parameter, but was unsuccessful.